# why we can't use eval with str in here?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Why this is achieved by `repr` method only?

```
import datetime
d=datetime.datetime.now()
x=str(d)
y=eval(x)
print(y)
```

It's showing

```
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Comment: Did you look at the strings you're trying to evaluate? Only one is syntactically valid Python.

Comment: Sorry, can you please be more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `str(datetime.datetime.now())`, you get a string representing the current time such as `2019-07-08 19:32:04.078030`.

But when `repr(datetime.datetime.now())` is called, the actual format of the datetime object is returned. Something like `datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 08, 19, 32, 4, 78030)`.

`eval()` evaluates the string as a python function. since `2019-07-08 19:32:04.078030` is not a python command, you get an error. `datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 08, 19, 32, 4, 78030)` however is a python command and is executed.

Overall the programs that will work are

Using `str()`:

```
import datetime
d=datetime.datetime.now()
x=str(d)
print(x)
```

Using `repr()`:

```
import datetime
d=datetime.datetime.now()
x=repr(d)
y=eval(x)
print(y)
```

Comment: But my programs runs fine when I am not using eval, why so?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean there are no errors?

Comment: yes, remove eval and there will be no error

Comment: Yes, removing eval will not result in an error but your output will now look something like `datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 08, 19, 32, 4, 78030)` instead of `2019-07-08 19:32:04.078030`

Comment: Yes, got the solution. Thanks